# Can't boot from Xubuntu USB stick

Tags: xubuntu, system-installation, live-usb

I want to install Xubuntu from my FAT32 Memorex 2GB 0058 TravelDrive. I currently have a Windows 8 64-bit system and I've already made the Xubuntu live USB using UNetbootin. I went to my BIOS and changed the boot order so that my USB flash drive boots first.

The USB started flashing so I know it was being accessed, but then the computer boots up Windows instead. I put 500MB into the startup memory option in UNetbootin and told it to specifically boot from the USB, but it still booted Windows, but the weird thing is is that I can run it perfectly in VirtualBox, so it has nothing to do with the .iso image I'm using.

Any answers are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

redownload the iso and try using a disk imager instead of unetbootin, I've just found that using an imager/partitioner many times has better results, just like how the normally burned windows recovery disks never work right, but you download an iso and it works perfectly :)